# Is it possible to create mobile application using WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-mobile, xbap

How would I get started? XBAP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 uses Silverlight for its application development.  I don't believe you're going to have a WPF-like option for older versions of Windows Mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could I use a WPF web-based app (xbap?) to make it viewable on mobile devices?

Comment: Sadly, no.  XBAP is going to rely on the .NET framework on the destination computer to be able to support that, and I'm not aware of any mobile devices that would support that particular version of the .NET stack.

Comment: What if you host the .XBAP on an asp.net server and a mobile device accesses the web page holding the application?

Comment: Still won't work.  The XBAP is downloaded and run at the client.